# How do I 'require' requirejs in a web js file?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs

I'm unsure how to implement requirejs in my code. I'm new to web development and HTML (I'm pretty good in JS)

You can't just natively use require(), so I have to use `requirejs`, but I'm unsure how to get it into my code. It's not like you can just do `require('requirejs')`. I've looked this up and haven't found an answer that works for me.

This is where I'm using requires:

```
function getDB(type,id){
    console.log(type,id)
    if (type === 'guild'){
        const guildData = require('./models/guilds.js')
        return guildData.findById(id);
    }
    else if (type === 'eco'){
        const ecoData = require('./models/economy.js')
        return ecoData.findById(id);
    }
    else if (type === 'staff'){
        const staffData = require('./models/staff.js')
        return staffData.findById(id);
    }
    else if (type === 'muted'){
        const mutedData = require('./models/muted.js')
        return mutedData.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Help me out here!

Comment: [They're pretty clear about the directions](https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html). But you need to [download](https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` from NodeJS is using CommonJS module format, but `require` from RequireJS is using AMD module format. They are non compatible.

Just adding RequireJS to your code will not make it work. You have to amend your code.

`require` from RequireJS does not return a required module. You have to pass the function which will have the module injected to it. Quick fix for you code:

```js
require(['./models/guilds', './models/economy.js', './models/staff.js', './models/muted.js',], (guildData, ecoData, staffData, mutedData) => {
    function getDB(type,id){
        console.log(type,id)
        if (type === 'guild'){
            return guildData.findById(id);
        }
        else if (type === 'eco'){
            return ecoData.findById(id);
        }
        else if (type === 'staff'){
            return staffData.findById(id);
        }
        else if (type === 'muted'){
            return mutedData.findById(id);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to download it and then you can add it as a script in HTML Code

```
<head>
   <title>My Sample Project</title>
   <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Getting this error? `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: You have add '<' some where extra in code. Can you share the code Please

Comment: I wasn't getting this error before adding the code above.

Here: https://hatebin.com/ntfeegkfgu

Comment: @Dog `node_modules/requirejs/` is not a JavaScript file. Try `src="https://unpkg.com/requirejs/require.js"`